# How can I get a text on a website into a variable?

Tags: python, pyautogui

With PyAutoGui I'm automating my working process. On a website, I have an integer at a very specific (x, y)-coordinate. Is it possible to transfer the integer value into a variable so I can do math with it?

I already tried copying the input and entering it into an input box, but the script always waits for an entry before I can use typewrite.

```
pyautogui.typewrite("\n")
pyautogui.moveTo(1850, 430, duration=5)
pyautogui.click()
#Now the Integer is marked; Can I get it stored in a variable?
```

I expect the integer to be stored in a variable (e.g. "amount.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyperclip is a wonderfully useful copy/paste module, even if you only use `pyperclip.paste()`. So, to add to your code:

```
import pyperclip

# first we use pyautogui to copy the text we highlighted to the clipboard
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

#now we use pyperclip.paste(), which sends the clipboard text to a variable
#also we need to cast the string to an int
try:
    amount = int(pyperclip.paste())
    #just checking we got what we need
    print(amount, type(amount))
except:
    print("Oh no. We didn't highlight an integer value.")
```